# How to opt out from observing @EnvironmentObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `@EnvironmentObject var model: Model` but i don't want to observe it but just use its methods. How to achieve that?

Comment: look into `protocol` and Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Environment instead and you'll need to make a custom key.